# Let a, b and c be positive real numbers such that abc=1. Let d = {a^(b+c)} * {b^(c+a)} * {c^(a+b)}. Find the maximum possible value of a.

Tags: calculus

Let a, b and c be positive real numbers such that abc=1. Let d = {a^(b+c)} * {b^(c+a)} * {c^(a+b)}.
Find the maximum possible value of d.

I found that the answer is 1 by using some hacks/fakesolve but I am unable to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean to find the maximum value of $d$?

Comment: Your post refers to "the maximum value of $a$" not $d$.  In any case, it might help to note that $d=\frac 1{a^a}\times \frac 1{b^b}\times \frac 1{c^c}$.

Comment: abc = 1, not a + b + c = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from S. Dolan is totally correct, but from your comment I guess you would like to see more intermediate steps.

If you want to find the maximum of $f$ it is the same as if you search for the maximum of $\ln (f)$. Therefore you can search for the maximum of $\ln (\frac{1}{a^a}\frac{1}{b^b}\frac{1}{c^c})$.

And this is just $-a\ln a - b\ln b - c\ln c$. Rather than maximising this you can also minimise this multiplied with minus 1.

And now you need to look up how you minimise a function with constraints by applying the method of Lagrange multipliers. You have to add to your function the constraint multiplied by $\lambda$:

$$ f =  a\ln a + b\ln b + c\ln c + \lambda (1 - abc) $$

This function you have to derive wrt $a, b, c$ and $\lambda$. This gives for $a$:

$$\frac{\delta f}{\delta a} = \ln a + 1 - \lambda bc = 0$$ or $$a \ln a + a = \lambda \hspace{1cm} (bc = \frac{1}{a})$$ and you get the same for $b$ and for $c$.

And since $a \ln a + a$ is a continuously increasing function, which means f(x) = f(y) => x = y, we can conclude that $a = b = c$. And from $abc = 1$ it follows that $a = b = c = 1$.

Is this now clear?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the simplification given by @lulu, we have to minimise $aln(a)+bln(b)+cln(c)$ subject to $abc=1$.

Using the method of Lagrange multipliers we have $$ln(a)+1=\lambda /a,ln(b)+1=\lambda /b,ln(c)+1=\lambda /c.$$

Then $$aln(a)+a=bln(b)+b=cln(c)+c$$

Since $xln(x)+x$ is an increasing function we have $a=b=c$. These variables and $d$ must therefore be $1$.

Comment: Yes, this answer does show that the max value of $d$ is $1$.